# r - maximum number of unique elements occurring for a given value in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, count, unique

Suppose I got a data frame like this:

```
> id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
> type = c("a","a","b","c","a","a","b","c","a","c")
> data = data.frame(id,type)
> data
   id type
1   1    a
2   1    a
3   1    b
4   1    c
5   1    a
6   2    a
7   2    b
8   2    c
9   3    a
10  3    c
```

I would like to find out what is the maximum number of **unique** types per id, but **NOT** the maximum among the values. Is there a one liner in the base package for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(data)[, list(type=uniqueN(type)) ,id]
```

Or

```
 library(dplyr)
 data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(type= n_distinct(type))
```

Or using `base R`

```
  aggregate(type~id, data, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Comment: @Marius You can use `aggregate(Type~id, data, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))`

Comment: True. Works with aggregate and then I just get the max from the aggregated column. Thanks. Can you add the aggregation solution in your answer to the question so I can mark it as official answer. Thanks again

Comment: @akrun I get this error when I try the data.table script: `Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(data), , list(type = uniqueN(type)), id) : 
  could not find function "uniqueN"`

Comment: @plafort I am using the `devel` version of `data.table`.  I think `uniqueN` was introduced in the devel version

Answer (score 0):

This line of complex looking code can do the trick for you:

`apply(table(data), MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x)names(which(x==max(x))))`

Let me break down the code to make it simpler.

We can use `table(data)` to get a summary of the dataframe - count of unique types in each id. Here's the result of running above snippet.

```
    type
id  a b c
  1 3 1 1
  2 1 1 1
  3 1 0 1
```

So we can see, there's 3 a's in id 1, whereas id 2 has 1 of each, a, b and c, and so on.

Now, going to the complex code - it will simply give col-names(type) which have maximum count for each id.
see help for `apply` and `which`

I hope this answers the question.
Let me know if you need further clarification on this.

edit: result of runnning the one liner are given below:

```
$`1`
[1] "a"

$`2`
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$`3`
[1] "a" "c"
```

i.e., type with maximum count in each id
that's what you asked, isn't it?